# How do I use Subgraph to sample the $n$ vertices of a graph with the greatest connectivity?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks, sorting

Let $G$ be an arbitrary graph with some number of vertices $||V||$ and some number of edges $||E||$.  We can use `Subgraph` to generate, well, a subgraph of `G` with the vertices we desire.  However, how can I use the `patt` option for `Subgraph` (or any method) to grab the set of `n` vertices with the greatest degree in $G$?  In other words, if we make a list `Sort[VertexDegree[G]]`, how can we select vertices for the subgraph starting from the right-hand-side of the output list then working our way to the left?

Comment: By using `Sort` you will lose the whole meaning of `VertexDegree`: the $i^{th}$ value returned by `VertexDegree` corresponds to the $i^{th}$ vertex. `VertexDegree` will only tell you the number of connections each vertex have.

Comment: @Öskå I just meant to use Sort to illustrate what I was trying to do do.  I'd like to use something like Select I suppose?

Comment: You want to extract each `Subgraph` and `Sort` them in terms of what `Sort@VertexDegree@G` would yield?

Comment: @Öskå Oh, I meant that I would like to generate subgraph consisting of the vertices with the greatest possible connectivity in the larger graph we're pulling the subgraph from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's take a `RandomGraph`:

```
SeedRandom@1;
g = RandomGraph[BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution[10, 2], VertexLabels -> "Name",
                  ImagePadding -> 20]
list = Reverse@SortBy[
         Thread[{Range@VertexCount@g, VertexDegree[g]}], Last@# &]
       (*{vi, vertexdegree@i}*)
```

> ```
> {{1, 7}, {2, 6}, {6, 5}, {4, 4}, {10, 2}, {9, 2}, {8, 2}, {7, 2}, {5, 2}, {3, 2}}
> ```

meaning that the vertex `1` has `7` neighbours, `2` has `6` and so on.

Then you can define the following function:

```
highlightSubgraph[list_] := HighlightGraph[g, Style[Subgraph[g, # <-> _], 
  Hue[#/VertexCount@g]], VertexLabelStyle -> {# -> {Red, Bold, 16}}, PlotLabel -> {#, #2}] 
  & @@@ list;
```

and plot every `Subgraph`:

```
highlightSubgraph@list
```

[image]

or plot only the first $n^{th}$:

```
highlightSubgraph@list[[1;;3]]
```

[image]

If you want to use a threshold you can of course `highlightSubgraph@Select[list, Last@# > n &]`

---

If you only want the `Subgraph` the following will do:

```
Subgraph[g, # <-> _, PlotLabel -> {#, #2}] & @@@ list[[1 ;; 3]]
```

[image]

Comment: Wait, why do the subgraphs have more than the three vertices?  I'm looking for the subgraph (connected or not) composed of only the vertices from the output of list[[1;;3]]?

Comment: Say we have a graph with five vertices connected in linear order (v1 <--> v2 <--> v3 <--> v4 <--> v5).  We then select vertices {v1, v2, v4} (in a more complex example, these would be the vertices with highest order).  Finally, we make the subgraph: {v1 <--> v2, v4 unconnected}.  Does this make sense?  We just want to grab the 'n' highest order vertices, and then grab all the edges these higher order vertices share with one-another, and draw a "subgraph" with just these grabbed vertices and edges.

Comment: So.., you want to make a `Graph` out of the shared vertices/edges of the first $n^{th}$ verticies?

Comment: One of the issue is that in the `Graph` I took I have no shared vertices between the 3 vertices with the greatest connectivity. See [here](http://i.imgur.com/5VAQLGg.png).

Comment: Can we just delete any unconnected vertices, or if possible, keep grabbing vertices in the order of their connectivity in the larger graph until we have a subgraph of the desired size?  The latter suggestion sounds maybe too hard, so I'd be fine with just deleting unconnected vertices.

Comment: By the way, thanks for working with me here.  After all, I messed up with my original question posting.

Comment: What would be the desired size then? And how do you actually plot that `Graph` in the end? If we stick with these 3 first vertices, what would it look like? 3 vertices with edges to shared vertices?

Comment: And please consider removing your former comments :) It's getting messier and messier here :)

Comment: @user13772 Even though I'm still confused about what you want I can propose you [this](http://pastebin.com/kkKTzRg9). You should consider doing sketches :)

Answer (score 0):

This question is not really about graphs, but about how to select *n* elements from list *A* so that the corresponding numbers in list *B* are the largest.

The best way is [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ordering.html), not `Sort` or `SortBy`.

Suppose your graph is `g`.  Then the *indices* of the `n` largest elements of `VertexDegree[g]` are

```
indices = Ordering[VertexDegree[g], -n]
```

Then just take `vertices = VertexList[g][[ indices ]];`, and finally `Subgraph[g, vertices]`.